# How to save Sockets in txt

Tags: java

I'am currently making a chat-server application.
to share the clientnames in an arraylist, which i'am saving in a txt file.

How could i do the same with the clients? 
I cant use a Scanner to read in sockets.

```
public static void writeList() throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("clientsname.txt"); 
    for(String str: clientsname) {
      writer.write(str + "\n");
    }
    writer.close();
}

public static void updateList() throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("clientsname.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        s.add(sc.next().trim());
    }
    clientsname = s;
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what it is exactly that you wish to save. You state "client" but what sort of object is a client? What data from client is it that you need? Your title is in error since you obviously can't save a Socket itself to text file, nor would you ever want to.

Comment: The client will have a read-side stream (`InputStream`) that can be passed to the Scanner class, but once you're done with it, the act of `close()`ing the scanner will close the stream, breaking the connection. If you showed us what you've tried on the client side, we might be able to give you better answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can save and read objects in textfiles with ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: What do you mean? You can make an ObjectOutputStream with your FileOutputStream in the constructor and write the object. Same for ObjectInputStream(just with FileInputStream). When you have read your object you cast it to the class it was saved as.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but are you really suggesting to use serialization to write to a *text* file? This will not create text in any readable form. There are ways to serialize in text readable fashion (JSON, XML via JAXB), but standard Java serialization is not one of them.

Comment: The op is asking to create a text file which means that it should contain readable text

Comment: Ok, I thought it should be readable to the application, not to humans.

Answer (score -1):

i am also working on the same thing ,but i didn't get what you meant by clients here ?
I am using a hashmap on server side which will manage all the users which are connected to the socket. I am using ping pong service by which user/client can ping to server for the connected users. 
If you are using managing in textfile ,that is not effective with real time .

Comment: at first. thanks for the tip. hashmap seems more logical.
but my problem is, that i use a server and threads as handler for manyclients.
So the clients cant access the same hashmap. or did i something wrong?

Comment: @furimi I am using only a websocket ,which i am using for two way communication .I think your implementation is different so i cant say on that.